# Which sequence is generated randomly?

Tags: probability-theory

Given the following two sequences:

sequence 1: 3,7,7,2,3,1,8,4,2,9,1,3,9,8,9,6,3,3,1,4,7,7,8,5,7,6, 1,7,8,3,2,6,8,5,7,4,4,3,9,9,6,8

sequence 2: 9,8,7,6,5,3,4,1,2,5,2,9,6,3,1,7,8,4,1,8,3,9,7,6,4,2,5,2,4,5,3,6,7,8,9, 1,7,5,8,3,6,4

The question is which sequence is more likely to stem from a random sampling from {1,...,9}? I thought about doing a calculation, but the question asks for an argument. My pick would be sequence 2: The numbers seem to be equally distributed. Is this correct?

Comment: It may be worth noting that all strings of length $N$ of digits from $1$-$9$ are equally likely to appear under uniform random sampling (all have probability $1/9^N$).

Answer (score 3):

In the second sequence the first nine digits are all different, the digits from the tenth to the eighteenth are all different etc - and you can work out the probability of that.

There are no double digits in the second (eg $7$ followed by $7$) - you would expect about one in nine pairs to be a double. Again, work out the probability of that.

There are some unlikely regularities in the second list which match some of the things which happen when human beings try to construct a random list.

Comment: Based on what you wrote, you're probably right that the second list is less likely to be random. However, as I stated in my comment to [David G. Stork](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/210401/david-g-stork)'s answer, the relatively high variance in frequencies of digits in the first list, from $2$ to $7$, also seems quite unusual, even for a relatively short list like this one. This could still imply that the first distribution is random, just likely to not be completely uniformly random.

Comment: @JohnOmielan It seems to me that this might be an exercise where there are reasons for choosing both as an introduction to systemic methods of testing randomness.

Comment: That was basicially what I thought as well. Properly testing randomness, without knowing anything much else, involves doing several checks (such as you did), not just assuming an uniform distribution and then doing a basic frequency test.

Answer (score 0):

The first list, because the second list has precisely equal probability of each numeral—an extremely unlikely case.

Comment: Both lists contain $42$ digits, so it's not possible for each digit to have "precisely equal probability". In fact, $0$, $1$ & $9$ appear $4$ times, & the other digits appear $5$ times. Although not "precise", the frequencies are no more than $1$ different. However, for the first list, the frequencies are, as ordered pairs of digit & freq., $(1, 4), (2, 3), (3, 7), (4, 4), (5, 2), (6, 4), (7, 7), (8, 6), (9, 5)$. In this case, there's a wide range of frequencies, going from $2$ to $7$. If assume uniform random sampling, this range seems unusually large, even for this relatively few values.

Comment: As I commented to [Mark Bennet]'s answer, it seems the first list is more likely to be random, but unlikely to be completely uniformly random. Does this seem reasonable to you?